# ruby - How to do if X is equal to either one of these values (xxx,eeee,yyyy,dadadad)

Tags: ruby

example if fileExt "doc"

if fileExt is equal to either ("doc", "xls", "ppt")

Any ideas?

Comment: *feels lack of some new kind of close reasons*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a regular expression:

```
do_x if file_ext =~ /\A(doc|xls|ppt)\Z/
```

Or, if you have a large enough list of things that writing a regex feels impractical, you could do something like

```
file_extensions = %w(xls csv doc txt odf jpg png blah blah blah blah blah)
do_x if file_extensions.include?(file_ext)
```

Of course there is always the option of testing each value individually:

```
do_x if file_ext == "doc" || file_ext == "xls" || ... || file_ext == "zzz"
```

Comment: good point @Phrogz, I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

you can make this to check if file extension between doc or xls or zzz:

```
file_ext = "doc"

if ["doc","xls","zzz"].include?(file_ext)

puts "true"

end
```